# Why won't this program work in VB 2010

Tags: xml, arrays, vb.net

Ok so I just got a ton of help in vb 2010. I need a little more from you guys if you would kindly.

I have an xml file here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<Data>
  <Person>
    <Name>hi</Name>
    <Email>222</Email>
    <Tel>2345</Tel>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>hank</Name>
    <Email>222</Email>
    <Tel>2345</Tel>
  </Person>
</Data>
```

And I want to put the Name, Email, and Tel into 3 separate arrays. I think i got it. But why isn't it working now. what is broken here.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2
    Dim array() As String
    Dim testname As String
    Dim namearray(1) As String
    Dim emailarray(1) As String
    Dim telarray(1) As String

    Public Const path As String = "MyName.xml" 'it is in the bin folder.

    Public Sub GetPerson()

        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
        settings.IgnoreComments = True
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = True

        Dim xmlIn As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings)

        If xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Person") Then
            Do
                Dim person As New Person
                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Person")
                namearray(x) = xmlIn("Name")
                emailarray(x) = xmlIn("Email")
                telarray(x) = xmlIn("Tel")
                x = x + 1
            Loop While xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Person")
        End If


        xmlIn.Close()


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        GetPerson()
        Search.Text = namearray(0)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Dim person As New Person` you instance a person, then never use it? We surmise from your previous adventures a person likely provides storage for Name, Email and Telephone, so why not use it?  Using a separate arrays to store data that goes together is a bad idea.  YOu might want to check that you are not off on the wrong track with this assignement...  Otherwise with the arrays of size 1 (`namearray(1)`) you cant go past 1 iteration of the loop.

Comment: Weren't you told, when you asked how to add something into an array, to use a List(Of String) instead, because you do not know the number of elements in your array?

Comment: @igrimpe previous posts indicated a List(of Person) http://stackoverflow.com/q/19621315/1070452 .  I doubt the assignment devolved from that to breaking up data into separate arrays for each data element.

Comment: @Plutonix: I'm getting confused slowly ;) He STARTED with a List(of Person) - but had no Person. After that he switched to arrays of string, but only had List(Of Person). Now Person is gone again (which means the code would not even compile), he has no list(of whatever), but instead he has fixed size arrays - and without trying to be mean, he has absolutely no clue what he is doing in his code.

Comment: Well the thing behind all of this is what i learned in class. I was wanting to just add them to the array and then go from there. I was wondering if you can do without the person class and load into the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

The book probably specifies more than this, but from what we have learned previously, there does seem to be a Person Class involved:

```
Friend Class Person
    Friend Name as String = ""
    Friend EMail As String =""
    Friend Phone as String = ""
End Class

Friend People As List(of Person)
```

Reading the XML; in the loop:

```
  ' I dont like instance names the same as Type names:
  Dim p As New Person
  xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Person")
  P.Name=xmlIn("Name")
  P.EMail = xmlIn("Email")
  P.Phone = xmlIn("Tel")

  ' Person now holds all the data for a this person.
  ' add him/her to the list:
  People.Add(p)

  ...
  n = 1
  For n as integer = 0 to People.Count-1
      console.WriteLine("Person #{0} is named {1)",n, People(n).Name)
  next n
```

Dont let the semi-confusing structure (Of..) confuse you.  All the `Of` clause does is specify what will be going into this list.  There are many other useful collection types in .NET such as a Dictionary and ArrayList depending on the job at hand.

The value of a List is that you do not have to know how many things you are loading. Moreoever rather than storing data related to a **single** thing (a person) in **different** arrays the Class allows the data to stay together. Imagine if you had to collect Occupation, Employer, Address, City, State/Province, Marital status, gender etc etc etc how many arrays you would have AND how difficult it would be to keep everything together.

Comment: I was trying to get them into arrays without adding the values into a new class. Do i have to have the person class